# Ubuntu 16.04: opencv python: Floating point exception

Tags: python, opencv

When I try to run the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I receive the message: `Floating point exception`

Where is my mistake?

Comment: This code correctly, you could explain how you installed opencv, if it is from the official repositories of ubuntu, you have compiled it manually, or you have installed it through pip.

Comment: thanks for your response

Comment: I used the following guide to install opencv: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/